# In Python 3, is it possible to import a file from a subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some scripts that used shared code in a different directory (that happens to be a subdirectory).

For various reasons, I do not want to package the shared code up into a Python package, nor do I want to dump all the files into a single directory, nor do I want to add the subdirectory to the path.

Is there any way to do a relative import & pull in the files in the subdirectory in Python 3?

In IPython3

```
import subdir.my_shared_library
```

works fine.

However, this fails in Python3, along with every attempt I've made to add `__init__.py` files and do relative imports explicitly like `import .subdir.my_shared_library`.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: If the subdirectory contains an `__init__.py`, even if that file is empty, python will consider the directory a package. If that directory is a subdirectory of the working directory for the script, then `import subdirpackage.modulename` should work fine, where modulename is the name of one of the files you want to import.

If you are running the scripts with a different working directory, you will need to add the subdirectory to the python path.

Answer (score 5):

You should only need to add an `__init__.py` to `\subdir` and then import via `from subdir import my_shared_library`. If you don't want to compile it into a package with the rest of your code, you could also append it to your `PATH` using  `sys.path.append('subdir')` or the typical export to `PYTHONPATH`. If you don't want to touch paths, you can just drop it in the global `site-packages`, or, alternatively, create a virtual environment through something like `pyvenv` and put your library in the package folder there.

Comment: @ Ben Hamner mentioned in the question that he didn't want to package the shared code in the subdirectory.

Comment: Oh right, he also mentioned not appending it to `PATH` though. I guess if it's really a shared library, it could just go into `site-packages`, whether it's the package folder in the local Python installation or the one in a `venv`.

Comment: Maybe he does not want to append to sys.path in code. Even though appending appending to PYTHONPATH has the same affect.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending to PYTHONPATH from the shell like

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:subdir; python your_program.py
```

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

But the better way to do it is to append to sys.path:

```
sys.path.append('subdir')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use absolute import:

```
import subdir.my_shared_library
```

It assumes that *the parent* of `subdir` is in `sys.path` as it is the case when you are running a Python script from the same directory (the parent).

It would work even if there were no `__init__.py` file in the subdirectory. `subdir` would be treated as an [implicit namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) in this case. Though you should not abuse this feature.

If you don't want `subdir` to be a Python package i.e., if you want to consider `my_shared_library` as a top-level module then add `subdir` itself to the python path (assuming bash syntax for the command and the empty original `PYTHONPATH` envvar):

```
$ PYTHONPATH=subdir python -m your_module
```

where `your_module.py` uses `import my_shared_library`. Or (worse)  add `sys.path.insert(1, 'subdir')` to your module directly.